# Buenas! Como haría para que me devuelva el índice de una tabla que tenga el valor mas grande

Tags: java

He probado esto... Pero me devuelve el valor del índice en vez del índice de la tabla.

```
   int tablaEjemplo [] = {4, 6, 3, 2, 8};
   
   int mayor = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tablaEjemplo.length; i++) {
        
        if (mayor < tablaEjemplo[i]) {
            mayor = tablaEjemplo[i];
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println(mayor);
```

Comment: perdón ya la corregí

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Quieres saber en qué posición dentro del array está el mayor? Pues guárdate el `mayor` y el valor de `i` en otra variable cuando se cumpla la condición del `if`.

Comment: Como? voy a volver a editar la pregunta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es guardar el valor mayor y su posición dentro del array, tienes que definir otra variable para que guarde la posición. Algo como lo siguiente:

```
int tablaEjemplo [] = {4, 6, 3, 2, 8};
   
    int mayor = 0;
    int posicion = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tablaEjemplo.length; i++) {
        
        if (mayor < tablaEjemplo[i]) {
            mayor = tablaEjemplo[i];
            posicion = i;
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println("El numero mayor es: " + mayor + " y está en la posición: " + posicion);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int tablaEjemplo [] = {4, 6, 3, 2, 8};

int valorMax=0;
        
        for(int i=0; i<=4;i++) {
                if(valorMax < tablaEjemplo [i]) {
                    valorMax=tablaEjemplo [i];
                }
        }
        System.out.println("El valor maximo es " + valorMax );
```

Comment: Si bien esto responde a la pregunta siempre es bueno explicar un poco lo que hace tu código y como lo hace para que sea de ayuda a otros usuario. ;)